# How to setup Multiple environments for mobile backed using API gateway and lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a mobile back-end set up on as:

Apigateway-->[Cognitico authorizer]AWS Lambda --> DyanmoDb

I have *one Environment setup for PROD*

I want to create another environment for DEV and UAT. For this purposes I have created **separate AWS account**. My lambda code is easy to deploy and I can create DynamoDB tables manually.

API gateway was created via the web console. Now I could export the API via swagger but when I import into another account I get the error below:

> Invalid authorizer ID specified. Setting the authorization type to CUSTOM or COGNITO_USER_POOLS requires a valid authorizer.

I could manually remove authorizers and import the swagger file but that seam like a hack.

So the questions:

1) Assuming having one account for PROD and another account for UAT is the right approach. What would proper/easier way to move API Gateway config from one AWS account to another?

2)Is there a better way to have multiple environments for kind of setup above? Any official recommendations?

Comment: Did you create a Mobile hub Project ?

Comment: no not a mobile hub project